# ESRI's new geoportal-server-catalog XSLT files

Tags: metadata, esri-geoportal-server

I am trying to implement the new geoportal 2.0.1 from ESRI's Github and I am having a lot of trouble finding the xslt stylesheets for many types, especially the arcgis-details.xslt
The file seems to be referenced to be in GEOPORTAL_INSTALLAITON/metadata/details/arcgis-details.xslt:

```
"arcgis": {
key: "arcgis",
evaluator: G.evaluators.arcgis,
interrogationXPath: "/metadata/Esri/ArcGISFormat",
identifier: "ArcGIS-Metadata",
detailsXslt: "metadata/details/arcgis-details.xslt",
}
```

But the files are not included in the repo and I can't find them anywhere.